# how to print complex json data in tree format using angular cli?

Tags: angular

**Data like this:**

**Print like this**

[image]

**Data like in image**

[image]

Comment: I can,t able to put data in json format so i put image please don't mind

Answer (score 1):

If printing the object like

```
console.log(obj);
```

doesn't help, JSON.stringify is the method you are looking for:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: I want to print on UI not in log

Comment: like using for loop but don't understand how to access using for loop

Answer (score 1):

From your comment in one answer:

> I want to print on UI not in log

I assume you want to print on the web browser view instead?

In your html template you can do this:

```
   <pre>{{ obj | json }}</pre>
```

(The `<pre>` tag preserves the spaces and prints object values neatly as in with hierarchy)

That will display the `obj` in the following format in the browser:

[image]

[Source](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)